# How access to build artifacts or variables from custom extenion

Tags: azure-devops

I have to create custom VSTS (Azure DevOps) extenions. I need to disaply in custom tab some additionals information fetch from build artifacts or build variables. I have found examples how use Controls.BaseControl to create custom tab, but var sharedConfig:

```
TFS_Build_Extension_Contracts.IBuildResultsViewExtensionConfig = VSS.getConfiguration();

 sharedConfig.onBuildChanged((build: TFS_Build_Contracts.Build) => {
  //How fetchartifacts from build
});
```

doesn't contain information about artifacts and queued variables.
So my question is, How can I fetch that info in class which extends Controls.BaseControl ? Maybe is another way to achive that.

```
import Controls = require("VSS/Controls");
import VSS_Service = require("VSS/Service");
import TFS_Build_Contracts = require("TFS/Build/Contracts");
import TFS_Build_Extension_Contracts = require("TFS/Build/ExtensionContracts");

export class StatusSection extends Controls.BaseControl {   
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    public initialize(): void {
        super.initialize();
        // Get configuration that's shared between extension and the extension host
        var sharedConfig: TFS_Build_Extension_Contracts.IBuildResultsViewExtensionConfig = VSS.getConfiguration();
        if(sharedConfig) {
            // register your extension with host through callback
            sharedConfig.onBuildChanged((build: TFS_Build_Contracts.Build) => {
                var buildId = build.id;
                                //needs variables or artifacts here
            });
        }       
    }
...
```